# Can you make the triviality of $\langle a,b,c \mid aba^{-1} = b^2, bcb^{-1} = c^2, cac^{-1} = a^2 \rangle$ more trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, group-presentation

I recently learned the following pleasant fact. (It was in the proof of Proposition 3.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303325) - but don't worry, there's no model theory in this question.)

Let $G$ be a group, and let $a,b,c\in G$. If $aba^{-1} = b^2$, $bcb^{-1} = c^2$, and $cac^{-1} = a^2$, then $a = b = c = e$. Put another way, the group defined by generators and relations $\langle a,b,c \mid aba^{-1} = b^2, bcb^{-1} = c^2, cac^{-1} = a^2 \rangle$ is the trivial group.

---

I came up with the following elementary, but ugly, proof:

The relations can be rewritten as (1) $ab = b^2a$, (2) $bc = c^2b$, (3) $ca = a^2c$.

Using (1), (2), and (3), we can rewrite $a^4bc = a^4c^2b = c^2ab = c^2b^2a$.

But we can also rewrite $a^4bc = b^{16}a^4c = b^{16}ca^2 = c^{2^{16}}b^{16}a^2$.

So $c^{2^{16}}b^{16}a^2 = c^2b^2a$. This implies $a = b^{-16}c^{2-2^{16}}b^2$.

Substituting for $a$ in (1) above, $b^{-16}c^{2(1-2^{15})}b^3 = b^{-14}c^{2(1-2^{15})}b^2$, and cancelling from both sides, $c^{2(1-2^{15})}b = b^{2}c^{2(1-2^{15})}$.

But now by (2), we have $bc^{1-2^{15}} = b^{2}c^{2(1-2^{15})}$, and $b = c^{2^{15}-1}$. But then $b$ and $c$ commute, so $bcb^{-1} = c^2$ implies $c = c^2$, and $c = e$. It then follows easily that $a = b = c = e$.

---

*Question:* Is there a better way to see this? i.e. a more abstract proof, or at least one that doesn't involve manipulating words of length $2^{16}$?

Comment: A slightly relevant remark, if there are four generators with similar relations, the group will be infinite. That is, $⟨a,b,c,d∣aba^{−1}=b^2, bcb^{−1}=c^2,cdc^{−1}=d^2, dad^{−1}=a^2⟩$ is not finite. c.f. Serre's Trees Page 9.

Comment: @userabc Thanks for the comment - this is actually the very next remark in the paper I linked to. But the authors just call it a "well-known fact", so it's nice to have the reference to Serre's book. And I see that my question is Exercise 1) on p. 10 of *Trees*.

Comment: ... and now that I can search for an exercise number in a well-known book, I find that there are a number of questions on this site about the same group. For example, Jim Belk gave almost an identical proof to the one I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1348319/7062), and Martin Brandenburg asked essentially the same question I'm asking [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479835/higman-group-with-3-generators-is-trivial). Together, this evidence makes me think that there's unlikely to be a nicer proof. It would be reasonable to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: There is another proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023341/).

Comment: How'd you get from $a^4b^2c$ to $c^2ab$?

Comment: Nevermind: $$\begin{align} a^4c^2b& =a^2(a^2c)cb\\ &=a^2(ca)cb \\ &=(a^2c)acb \\ &=(ca)acb \\ &=c(a^2c)b \\ &=c(ca)b \\ &=c^2ab. \end{align}$$

Comment: Once you have proved that $a \in \langle b,c \rangle$, you can use the more conceptual argument given  by Bhaskar Vashishth in the linked proof, that $G$ is perfect, but $G = \langle b,c \rangle$ is solvable, so $G$ is trivial.

Comment: A quantitative question would go as follows: triviality of $G$ means that one can write, in $F_3$, $a=w$, $w=\prod_{i=1}^ng_ir_ig_i^{-1}$ with $r_i$ among the the three relators. (a) what's the smallest $n$ for this this exists (this is the "area" of the relation)? (c) what is the smallest length $\sum_i(2|g_i|+|r_i|)$ of such a writing? (c) what's the smallest radius (this is, in the loop given by $a^{-1}w$, the largest radius).

Comment: haha; by coincidence, I just got this problem as an exercise in one of my courses!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presentation $\langle x,y,z\mid xyx^{-1}y^{-2},yzy^{-1}z^{-2},zxz^{-1}x^{-2}\rangle$ of group equal to trivial group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023341/presentation-langle-x-y-z-mid-xyx-1y-2-yzy-1z-2-zxz-1x-2-ran)

Comment: How is that a better way, @635318657?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of what a better proof would be.